# Auto generating gallery of images

Tags: images, openoffice, automation, image-gallery

I have a few hundreds of images and I'd like to generate a "gallery" out of it. The problem is I'd like to have it in ODT or at least in PDF(or sth that I can print nice to PDF). It will be printed, it should look neutral (it's an grave reference for archaeology paper) each image will have caption. Images have different sizes. What software would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).  Then open a command window or terminal.  Assuming all your images are jpegs & they live in the current directory, type:

```
montage -label %f\n%wx%h\n%b -frame 5  -tile 6x\
        -background #999999 -geometry 60x60+4+4 *.jpg test.pdf
```

This will generate thumbnails, 6 to a row,  each tile exactly 60x60, with the aspect ratio preserved, so there might be some blank around your image.

Your output might look like:

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice, seen people recommending Imagemagick a few times on here, but I have never really looked in to it, this looks cool (and thanks for the example) I am going to look in to this for a project I have coming up.

Answer (score 3):

See this article, ["Convert JPG to PDF (or other image formats to PDF)"](http://www.novapdf.com/kb/convert-jpg-to-pdf-or-other-image-formats-to-pdf-105.html).

The idea behind this article is simple enough : combine an image-viewer software, such the Windows Photo Printing Wizard, Picasa, or IrfanView, together with a virtual PDF printer. You then just print the images you choose to the pdf printer, to generate the gallery as a pdf file.